# Conditionally throwing based on pre-fetched result stored in a temp table inside a function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I need to apply some validation rules on set of a data I've fetched for a given account in order of using postgres v9.6:

1. Fetch all rows applicable to account.
2. For each validation rule, query subset of in step 1, and throw where condition isn't met.

And this is how I am doing it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.my_function(account_id character varying)
RETURNS boolean
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN

    -- dump all relvant rows for account_id into temp table
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table ON COMMIT DROP
        AS
        SELECT ...

    -- validation 1
    IF EXISTS (SELECT ...
               FROM my_temp_table
               WHERE ...
              ) THEN raise  exception 'failed validation 1'

    -- validation 2
    IF EXISTS (SELECT ...
               FROM my_temp_table
               WHERE ... and ... and ...
              ) THEN raise  exception 'failed validation 2'

    -- validation 3 with bit more logic to it
    IF EXISTS (WITH my_cte AS 
               (
                   SELECT CASE WHEN ... IS NULL THEN 'foo' END AS r
                   FROM my_temp_table
                   WHERE ...
               )
               SELECT r
               FROM my_cte
              ) THEN raise exception 'failed on validation 3';

    -- If we got here, then all is well
    return true;

END;
$function$
```

The function is called as `select * from public.my_function('xxxxxx');`

Above works, but I'm not 100% sure if usage of temporarily table is correct here!

- Will I get into trouble of `table my_temp_table already exist` if multiple queries come through all at the same time?
- If I don't do it using Temp table, how else should I do this?

PS. Obviously not an DB expert here so feel free to criticise/advise as you see fit :)

Comment: Is lack of answers here cause above can only be done using temp table? Or am i not clear with my question?